# Verify the current Google Chrome installation's integrity

Tags: software-installation, google-chrome, md5sum

I have installed Google Chrome from the `.deb` file provided [here](https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb), but after I installed it I realised that I had not checked the MD5 of the `.deb` file to make sure that it was not corrupt or tampered with (as some of the other software that I was downloading at that time had the wrong MD5 and I had to re-download) before I installed Google Chrome and then deleted the `.deb` file.

I have two, linked questions:

1. Is there any way in which now I can verify the integrity of my current Google Chrome installation? Perhaps during the installation an application would have logged the MD5? Or perhaps with the key that it would have been signed with I can still test without a reinstall of Google Chrome?
2. Where can I find the official MD5 for Google Chrome? I have been unable to find this on their website.

Comment: The only way to 100% avoid attack is to use a [**DNSSEC**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System_Security_Extensions) download server.

Comment: Example: 0.  **Google.com** contain [many erros](https://zonemaster.iis.se/?resultid=1fce1e919334f61b). 1. **UBUNTU.ORG** [contais many warnings](https://zonemaster.iis.se/?resultid=a3fd40fc8f4108eb) so `apt` is exposed. 2. **DEBIAN.ORG** use DNSSEC but contains an [address warning](https://zonemaster.iis.se/?resultid=1eb3feae023228a5) ,  *"Nameserver dns4.easydns.info has an IP address (2620:49:4::10) without PTR configured"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the easiest method of verifying a deb is via `apt`

See [How secure is the apt-get install command against man in the middle attacks](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/10106/how-secure-is-the-apt-get-install-command-against-man-in-the-middle-attacks) and the [Securing Debian Manual](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/securing-debian-howto/ch7.en.html) for details.

This does not help you, however, if you did not install the package via `apt`.

It then depends on how the .deb was packaged. If it was "properly" packaged it should include md5sums of the files

Look in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/google-chrome.md5sums` I am not sure of the exact file name here.

You can also use the -V or dpkg --verify options

```
dpkg --verify google-chrome

-V, --verify [package-name...]
          Verifies  the  integrity  of  package-name  or  all  packages if
          omitted, by comparing information from the installed paths  with
          the database metadata.

          The output format is selectable with the --verify-format option,
          which by default uses the rpm format, but that might  change  in
          the  future,  and  as  such programs parsing this command output
          should be explicit about the format they expect.
```

[Man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/dpkg.1.html)

If you installed a compromised package and the person was good, or the person who packaged the .deb did not follow standard protocols, you really can not verify the package as the md5sums will be good (in the first case) or missing (in the second case).

This is an example of why you should not install packages outside of the ubuntu repositories (use [Chromium](http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/chromium-browser)) and why I advise people who package follow the packaging guidelines. Although the guidelines are a hassle, they are important.

Comment: The repros are quite limited... Isn't that a little overkill?

Comment: I ran the command `dpkg --verify google-chrome-stable` with `sudo` as it did not very well before,  and the the command seems to have been executed usefully, although there was no output, does this mean that the files match the MD5sums of those in the file?

Comment: @Tim - overkill?

Comment: Not installing outside repros. Isn't that going a little far to be safe?

Comment: @Tim - depends on your position on security. Just because something, a script or a binary or a lib is packaged as a .deb in no way ensures the package is safe or secure. I can package a modified version of sudo into a .deb and even included a valid package such as google-chrome . As people use more and more ppa and install things outside of the official repos I anticipate more problems with social engineering.

Comment: Fair point. How can I be safe if I require external packages? (e.g. Chrome because I develop on it at home and work).

Comment: Is there anyway that I could compare the contents of my `/var/lib/dpkg/info/google-chrome-stable.md5sums` to that of another installation? But as I don't want to do another installation, could I get it by extracting the contents of the deb file, or do I get it from somewhere else?

Comment: @Tim - Also, in order to be in the Ubuntu repositories a package has to follow the packaging guidelines - https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/ This includes naming conventions and lintian. If these standards are not followed, breakage can occur. For example, in you convert a .rpm to a .deb via alien or install from source, shared libs can be over written due to conflicts in naming conventions. This can result in breakage, either in the package or even in apt. You can only be as safe as the source of the code.

Comment: Extract a known good .deb and compair the .md5sums file - http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/04/view-and-extract-packages/ . You can use diff `diff /file/in/extracted/.deb /file/on/your/system` or even script it.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: The slight problem with that is that I am unable to find the `.md5sums` file in the `.deb` file that I extracted the contents from. So where is it usually located within the `.deb` file?

Comment: If there is no md5sums file you will need to manually generate one or use the diff command.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: So if I do not have the md5sums file, then what will I compare with diff?

Comment: And how would I generate it myself?

Comment: md5sum /path/to/files/* >> chromium-browse.md5sums . diff /path/to/file1 /path/to/same_file/on/system

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: Is there not a faster and more efficient way of doing this? Could I not get it to just generate a file with all of the md5sums of all of the files in the extracted deb file folder, and then compare the lines (not matter the order) to the other .md5sums file?

Comment: you can try ... Again diff is your friend. diff known_good suspect_file

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: So there is no way of automating the process? I have to use diff to do it manually?

Comment: if dpkg -V fails, then yes it is a manual confirmation. Again a disadvantage of installing the way you did. If you used apt and if the package were up to standards ...

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: Wait, so how do I use `dpkg -V` to check the files that I have installed against the ones in the extracted .deb file? Or is that not how I do it?

Comment: It does not appear the package is properly configured. It it were you would just run `dpkg -V google-chrome`

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: I ran that, and it seems to have executed successfully, although it is checking in the changelog file, which appears scrambled...

Comment: You will have to either trust dpkg -V or manually run diff or md5sum checking, up to you.

Comment: About DNSSEC?  Example: 0.  **Google.com** contain [many erros](https://zonemaster.iis.se/?resultid=1fce1e919334f61b). 1. **UBUNTU.ORG** [contais many warnings](https://zonemaster.iis.se/?resultid=a3fd40fc8f4108eb) so `apt` is exposed. 2. **DEBIAN.ORG** use DNSSEC but contains an [address warning](https://zonemaster.iis.se/?resultid=1eb3feae023228a5) ,  *"Nameserver dns4.easydns.info has an IP address (2620:49:4::10) without PTR configured"*.